# Spaces between characters is funky in linked or embedded documents in Word 2016 for Mac

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

In Word 2016 for Mac, when I create two documents ("A" and "B"), the character spacing in both documents is good. But when I link or embed Document B into Document A, the spacing between characters in the linked/embedded text in Document A is bad, with either too much or too little space between characters.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest disabling kerning in both of the documents.

> Highlight the text in question.
>   Pick the Tools option from the Font menu.
>   In the Font dialog box which appears, make sure the Character Spacing tab is selected.
>    Click off the Kerning for Fonts check box, then click OK.

Should that fail, enable it in both documents.